# PHP deleting last 7 day login attempt query error

Tags: mysql-workbench

I have following MySQL query to delete last 7 days login attempts;

```
DELETE FROM LoginAttempt WHERE LoginAt < DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY )
```

I get this error when I run in Workbench;

Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect. 0.032 sec

Here is my table;

```
    CREATE TABLE LoginAttempt(
    LoginId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    IpAddress VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    LoginAt DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
    PRIMARY KEY(LoginId)
);
```

Comment: these not mysql error your editor error

Comment: Have you tried toggling the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect?

Comment: @PeeHaa.. thanks. I disabled safe update and reconnected. Not query runs. However, it shows, "0 rows affected". and nothing has changed. Yes, i want to remove rows older than 7 days. Sorry for my english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to remove the rows older than 7 days... Anyway to disable the safe mode you must uncheck this option in Edit > Preferences:

[image]

Comment: thanks. I disabled safe update. Not query runs. However, it shows, "0 rows affected". and nothing has changed. Yes, i want to remove rows older than 7 days. Sorry for my english

Comment: Are there records older than 2016-06-22?

Comment: Thanks a lot. How stupid I am ! now i checked. it now works. I will have to check thin in cPanel cron job. Then if I face another problem, I will tell you and accept your answer. thanks

Answer (score 2):

> I have following MySQL query to delete last 7 days login attempts;
>
> `DELETE FROM LoginAttempt WHERE LoginAt < DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY )`

Lucky for you, you have that Safe Mode 'On'.

Your query is going to delete all the rows **older than 7 days**.

In order to delete the **last 7 days** of information, you should do:

`DELETE FROM LoginAttempt WHERE LoginAt > DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY )`

Comment: Senra. thanks. I disabled safe update. Not query runs. However, it shows, "0 rows affected". and nothing has changed. Yes, i want to remove rows older than 7 days. Sorry for my english

Comment: Before making a delete statement, always make a SELECT one first to make sure you're going to delete the correct data before triggering the action.

`SELECT * FROM LoginAttempt WHERE LoginAt < DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY )`

and see if that matches the records you want to delete. If not, then your query is not fine.

Comment: Oh my god! how really nice simple trick! I learnt a new thing. Thanks. I fixed my problem. Next I have to try this in cPanel cron job and let you know the result.

Comment: @AmaliPerera glad it helped. :)